# ¿como mostrar datos en un JTextField al presionar un jbutton?

Tags: java

Como puedo obtener que me imprima en el JtexField que es txtCodigo al presionar el botón.

```
   private void jbGenerarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    Random1 ran = new Random1();
    ran.llenarMatriz();
    ran.imprimirMatriz();
    txtCodigo.setText(jbGenerar.getText()); }
```

esta es la clase `Random1`

```
private int matriz[][];
private Random random;

public Random1() {
    this.matriz = new int[1][10];
    random = new Random();
}

public void llenarMatriz() {
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<matriz.length; j++) {
                matriz[i][j] = random.nextInt(50000);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void imprimirMatriz() {
    for(int i = 0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<matriz.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero tendrías que pasarlo a `string`, porque me parece que en `jtextfield` solo permitía que fuera eso, y luego `setText`.

```
ElString = String.valueOf(matriz[i][j])+"\t";
jTextField1.setText(ElString);
```

Creo que podría ser una cosa así, espero estar ayudando.

Answer (score 0):

No has especificado qué es lo que quieres imprimir concretamente en el JTextField. Supongo por tu código que lo que quieres es imprimir todos los valores de la matriz en el textflied. Para eso te propongo algo como esto:

1. Añade a tu clase `Random1` un getter para poder obtener la matriz desde la clase que contiene el JTextField:

`public int[][] getMatriz(){
        return matriz;
    }`

2. En la clase que maneja en botón y el textfield:

`boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int[][] matriz = ran.getMatriz();
        for(int i = 0;i < matriz[0].length;i++){
            txtCodigo.setText(txtCodigo.getText().toString() + "\t" + matriz[0][i]);
        }
      }
    });`

Eso es todo. Espero haber entendido tu pregunta. Si no es asi, especifica más por favor.